# How to alter the column type which is a foreign key in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two table customer and Address

**Customer** table has fields

> - cust_id (PK) BINARY(16)
> - address_id (FK) BINARY(16)
> - cust_name VARCHAR(32)

**Address** table has fields

> - address_id (Pk) BINARY(16)
> - address_name VARCHAR(250)

Now I need to modify the column type for address_id from BINARY(16) to CHAR(36) , but I am getting the error:

I am doing like this

> ALTER TABLE Addresses MODIFY COLUMN address_id CHAR(16);
>
> ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './ShipMileData/#sql-531_240'
>   to './ShipMileData/Addresses' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint from the `Customer` table. Then `ALTER` the column types in both tables, and add back the FK.